# Ext JS Message Box Position

Tags: extjs

I have a very 'long' screen and apparently when I am using the Ext JS 3.3.1 messagebox, it goes all the way to the bottom and removed everything in the background.

This is some example code:

```
Ext.Msg.show({
    title:'[SOME TITLE]',
    msg: '[SOME MESSAGE]',
    buttons: Ext.Msg.YESNO,
    fn: function (btn){
        if(btn=='yes'){     
            //Do something
        }
    }
},
icon: Ext.Msg.QUESTION}
);
```

Comment: Is there a question in there somewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
    Ext.MessageBox.show({
       msg: 'Saving your data, please wait...',
       progressText: 'Saving...',
       width:300,
       wait:true,
       waitConfig: {interval:200},
       icon:'ext-mb-download', //custom class in msg-box.html
       animEl: 'mb7'
  });
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The solution I was looking for was: box.getDialog().setPosition(x,y)

Answer (score 5):

So you want to set only the Y position of your MessageBox? Do this:

```
var msg=Ext.Msg.show({
    title:'[SOME TITLE]',
    msg: '[SOME MESSAGE]',
    buttons: Ext.Msg.YESNO,
    fn: function (btn){
        if(btn=='yes'){     
            //Do something
        }
    }
});
msg.getDialog().getPositionEl().setTop(50); //this is enough for Y position only
```

Using setPosition do this:

```
msg.getDialog().setPosition(undefined,50)
```

I used 50 pixels in this example because that's near the top. You can set it to something else from the top.